# Why do so many people claim that 'Classical Statistics' is 'wrong'?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I keep reading stuff about how Classical Statistics is 'wrong' or 'no longer relevant'. Some of them claim that machine learning will replace Classical Statistics, some of them claim that Bayesian Statistics is how Statistics should be done. Examples:

http://www.stats.org.uk/statistical-inference/

http://hps.elte.hu/seminar/2004/May-June/classicalstats.pdf

This makes Classical Statistics sounds extremely controversial and shouldn't be trusted at all.

I am a beginning student of Statistics and I am concerned about studying the 'wrong' (or very irrelevant/outdated) things. I am reading 'Introduction to the Theory of Statistics' by Mood, Graybill, and Boes, how do I know if this book teaches 'good' statistics? How do I know which textbook teaches 'correct' Statistics?

Comment: There are plenty of people who write that 'classical statistics is wrong', & there have been for generations. Nowadays, there are plenty of people who say that 'classical statistics is no longer relevant' & we should all just be building decision tree models, neural networks, SVMs, or whatever is the latest machine learning craze, instead. Both groups are small, vocal minorities. In the real world (ie, outside of internet forums), for better or worse *almost everyone* uses frequentist methods almost all the time (& probably via Excel!).

Comment: From the first site: "The twin evils of the egalitarianism of political correctness and null hypothesis testing are self reinforcing" & "PC fascists hate Bayesian methods, because Bayesian inference explicitly forces them to put their prejudices in the prior where everyone can see them". Oh, & a big picture of Hitler! Don't believe everything you read on the internet. Anyway, in a nutshell, what's outdated is the 20th Century spat about "the" foundations of inference.

Comment: Polemics can make for entertaining reading, but rarely advance scientific study.

Comment: You read a lot further into that site than I did, @Scortchi. It looked like garbage after a minute, so I stopped.  From your comment, I went back & read some more.  I was expecting Hitler to be associated w/ frequentism as a [reductio ad Hitlerum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Hitlerum), but the context seems to take Hitler as good or right. So perhaps this is an *augeo ad Hitlerum*?  Maybe the argument is we should all be Bayesians because Hitler was a Bayesian?  I dunno...  My guess is most Bayesians wouldn't use this as their main argument for Bayesianism.

Comment: @gung: So Hitler was a Bayesian, *ergo* not a fascist; the real fascists are the politically correct frequentists with their egalitarian null hypotheses. Got it.

Comment: The people who say this nonsense are probably in social sciences, where the whole thing seems wrong, not just the statistics

Comment: What is this site www.stats.org.uk ? Seems like it exists only to promote Bayesian Statistics (what it calls "Good" at http://www.stats.org.uk/uncertainty/) and discourage frequentist statistics (what it calls "Bad")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Frequentist statistics, which is what I'm sure is meant by "classical statistics" is not *wrong*. As a commenter on the Andrew Gelman blog once said (sorry, don't recall who), "Frequentist statistics isn't even in the category of things that can be wrong".

Really, the issue with Frequentist statistics, and more specifically significance testing, is that it is **confusing**. In particular, it's very easy to  misinterpret significance tests, which can then lead to backwards conclusions. Many statistical researchers, myself included, believe that the level of confusion about these methods has had very negative effects on other scientific areas of research that may misuse these methods.

To help illustrate, most significance tests look at the evidence against the hypothesis "a certain effect size is 0", otherwise known as the null hypothesis, and then computes the probability of seeing data as extreme as we observed, *under the assumption that the effect size is 0*. This is the p-value, and small p-values are considered evidence against the null hypothesis. If the p-value is below some pre-specified values $\alpha$, then we say we have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis.

Sound confusing? I warned you.

Some (but definitely not all!) of the common mistakes that occur:

- Some researchers make the mistake of thinking failing to reject the null means we should accept the null. But the lack of evidence is not itself strong evidence: small sample sizes often lead to failing to reject the null, even though it is false.
- Multiple testing. Significance testing requires that all your methods for analyzing data be planned *in advance of seeing the data*. In reality, this is not what usually happens. The strength of evidence presented by a p-value is greatly distorted when you have looked at 30 different questions, then present the one question that looks most promising.
- Thinking that rejecting the null hypothesis is a big deal. Very often, researchers will over emphasize how important a finding is by saying it is statistically significantly different than 0. However, that by itself is often not very interesting: if I tell you that I have strong evidence that my after school study program improves grades, if you *really* care, you should follow up with "by how much (magnitude of effect)? If I'm already studious, will it still help (consistency of effect)?". Typical usage of significance testing does not address this, yet some research papers don't pursue much beyond "we found our treatment had a statistically significant improvement over control". In fact, if your goal is to find statistical significance in your data, the typical usage of these methods in many fields *discourage* asking these deeper questions!

As for how to avoid making such mistakes, I'm not sure Bayesian statistics is an immediate cure-all. After all, Bayesian statistics has its own form of significance testing and Andrew Gelman, a firmly pro-Bayesian, anti-significance testing kinda fellow isn't a huge fan of Bayesian null hypothesis testing either. But at the very least, I think taking a course in Bayesian statistics is extremely helpful in helping you think properly about statistical methods, even if you always use "classical" methods. A full explanation of why I think a course in Bayesian statistics helps is a bit long for this answer, unfortunately.

Most importantly, to protect yourself from making mistakes with classical methods, you should understand what significance testing does and does not tell you about your data. Most books that feature classical methods are very careful about properly explaining what significance testing really implies, but not all readers pick up on some of the very important subtle details about how to properly interpret p-values.

Comment: Do (reputable) universities mostly teach Classical Statistics? I want to do a masters in Statistics but I am worried about doing a degree that teaches mostly irrelevant/outdated stuff. Would love to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: If you intend doing a master's in statistics, then you should definitely be familiar with frequentist methods. Perhaps you won't be using them frequently (pun intended) but you certainly need to understand them.

Comment: Just to add a few cents to this answer: To math people these tests are not confusing because they are just the statistical versions of regular 'proofs by contradiction', i.e. assume that they (means, variances, whatever) were not different too much then ... then something pops out that is very weird (namely that the (t- for example) statictics lies in an area where there is very little density) so the original assumption must be wrong.

Comment: Also the fact that these tests 'do not offer an answer to the question "by how much?"' is not completely true: Example: t-test for mean1 > mean2: You specify a candidate for the difference and some $\alpha$ and then you get 'yes or no'. This is NOT how this test works:´. I would rather view it as a function candidate -> p-value and then you get a curve that looses confidence in the fact that the means are apart by at least 'candidate' with increasing candidate. Where this loss in confidence is and how quickly it drops tells you 'by how much' and how confident the test is...

Comment: Also: Universities teach you the basics of measure theory, prob spaces, ..., i.e. things that you need to do *any* statistics (let it be frequentist or bayesian or whetever the future brings) at all, i.e. without these courses you can not really understand what is going on. A very basic example: I wondered for a while why people write / are allowed to write $p(x) = f_X(x)$ for densities and also $p(x) = P[X=x]$ for discretely valued RVs...

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan: You will certainly learn about Frequentist statistics during a Master's. I wouldn't call it irrelevant or outdated though. Just make sure you take a course on Bayesian statistics and Machine Learning and I think you will be very well rounded.

Comment: Agreed with "not sure Bayesian statistics is an immediate cure-all." - Olle Haggstrom gives a nice talk where a poorly chosen prior leads to nonsense.  Also, Tim Sullivan et al have written shown "brittleness" in the prior.  So I guess, while sledgehammers are very useful, one should take care.

Answer (score -2):

## It's all in your head

I'm sorry to be so melodramatic but it is really equivalent to the notion  that Newton laws are outdated (and yes, they are, quantum physics turned Newton and most of classical physics on its head)

However, nobody tells you to throw them away.

Now, it's up to you what books you study, and Mood, Graybill, and Boes is a great **theoretical** basis. What to do with that knowledge, is up to you, getting through the book will take months, getting through the fun reads you posted will take an evening.

thats why I said it: **it is all in your head**, not in the book.

Comment: I don't think the comparison to Newtonian physics is a good analogy.

Comment: (-1) As implied by my answer, I don't think classical statistics is "wrong", but I do think the question is asking about a very important issue that is very relevant to many fields of science. Simply saying "it's all in your head" rather than encouraging exploration of the issue is a disservice I believe.

Comment: qwr. I would point out that no analogy is `good`. My answer was intended to be short.
Cliff, I appreciate your comment. I disagree about `disservice`. I am trying to say that the basics have to be learned first. Sometimes simpler answers just work better. One can seek the right book for years. If you do research in statistics, you know that it is not the books, it is how you read them and what you are getting from them. Most books, that is.